Почему не открываются последующие формы с кнопок
Не могу понять, почему не открываются формы с кнопок. На главной форме разместил 5 кнопок, в кнопках код на вывод новых форм, первая работает, а остальные нет, может есть что то вроде ограничения, но тогда вопрос как сделать?
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ДКР
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 z1 = new Form2();
            z1.Show();
        }
        private void button2_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form3 z2 = new Form3();
            z2.Show();
        }
        private void button3_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form4 z3 = new Form4();
            z3.Show();
        }

        private void button4_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form5 z4 = new Form5();
            z4.Show();
        }
        private void button5_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form6 z5 = new Form6();
            z5.Show();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = "Работу выполнил:";
        }
    }
}


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO!  Вопросы , которые не стоит задавать:=>
Поиск ошибок, которые нельзя воспроизвести =>https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic
Как задать хороший вопрос => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Ребят, я не могу вам подробнее объяснить, подскажите, что непонятно, я добавлю в вопрос

А эти все методы точно на событиях соответствующих кнопок висят? Или вы их просто скопировали в коде с button1_Click? Зайдите в свойства конопок и посмотрите там события, в частности OnClick, или просто Click, не помню уже. Привязаны ли там к событию Click соответствующие методы для каждой кнопки?

Спасибо, помогло, но странно что метод не привязался к события, хотя кнопки с главной формы "прокликаны"

@CrazyElf, не подскажете, почему так могло произойти? Для общего развития...

Ну мало ли что. Может вы эти методы переименовывали в коде после создания событий прокликиванием. Не знаю )  Кстати, подозрительно, что у них у всех _click с маленькой буквы, а у первого с большой.
